# Getting Sum of a Class Attribute (of type integer) In all Instances

Tags: swift

Say that I have a class as such:

```
class Test  {
    var Test_Value: Int

    init?(Detail_Test_Value: Int) {
        self.Test_Value = Detail_Test_Value
    }
}
```

`Test_Value` is an integer class attribute. Say I have many instances of the class `Test`, all with unique values of `Test_Value`. What I aim to do is to obtain the sum of `Test_Value` from all of the instances. What are potential ways of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no magical "all instances of a class that I've created" function in Swift that I am aware of.

In order to sum up the values of all of your Test instances you need a way to track them all. You could add a class variable to hold an array of all of them, but you'd have to deal with the fact that that would cause them to all be held strongly and could cause a memory leak.

### Edit:

See this link for various ways to manage an array of weak references: https://marcosantadev.com/swift-arrays-holding-elements-weak-references/

(I suggest the `WeakRef` approach at the end.)

Comment: XCode has a memory debugger, which lists all instances(addresses) of a class at runtime. I am wondering how is XCode doing it? When we enable memory debugger, the debugging gets paused, so I guess at that moment Memory Debugger starts looking up memory addresses. The question is how are they doing it?